# Display colors in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, colors

Would it be possible for me to print a color in my terminal without using the colors from my .Xresources? For example, `echo -e "\033[32m Test"` will print "Test" but it's in the color that I've defined as green in my .Xresources. That being said, how would I print a color that isn't defined, such as #FF0000 without redefining my preset.

Answer (score 3):

Colours in a terminal (shell) window have no real relation to colours in your `.Xresources` file.

If you want to print colours in a terminal (shell) window you should seriously consider the `tput` command. This uses the `terminfo` database to generate the necessary escape sequences to obtain colours (amongst other things).

You can `man 5 terminfo` and read the section on `Color Handling`. Here's the table of available colours:

```
Colour    Value RGB
black     0     0, 0, 0
red       1     max,0,0
green     2     0,max,0
yellow    3     max,max,0
blue      4     0,0,max
magenta   5     max,0,max
cyan      6     0,max,max
white     7     max,max,max
```

and you use the `setaf` (set ANSI foreground) and `setab` (set ANSI background) commands to set them. Use `sgr0` to reset them afterwards.

For example

```
tput setaf 4    # Blue text
tput setab 3    # Yellow background
echo -n "This is blue text on a yellow background"
tput sgr0       # Reset colours
echo
```

Comment: If your terminal reads `~/.Xresources` (eg., rxvt or xterm), then it *will* use the colours defined there.

Comment: @jasonwryan I've not seen that behaviour but I'll check it (tomorrow). Thanks for the pointer

Comment: @roaima I believe that's what's happening with me. When I try to print a color such as red it will print what I've defined as red in my .Xresources

Comment: @Erich and @jasonwryan I can't reproduce this. I've added a series of `*colorN: #rrggbb` entries in my `~/.Xresources` and run `xrdb -merge` on it. A new `xterm` still seems to give me the standard set of colours for `tput setaf $af`

Comment: I guess I still don't understand, so setting `blackf="${esc}[30m";`, then printing later in that script `${blackf}This is a test` will print the black I've defined in my `~.Xresources` and my terminal's config. If it helps I'm using termite.

Comment: This only works for me if I use `printf` in place of `echo -n`. Redhat 7, bash 4.2.46

Comment: @CharlesBurns what happens instead?

Comment: @roaima Text is displayed normally, as if no `tput` was used.

Comment: Result of `echo "$TERM"` please, @charlesburns, and the terminal emulator or device that you're using

Answer (score 0):

Some terminal emulators support direct RGB true colors. See https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728 for details and usage examples.

Comment: That Gist is excellent. If you could summarise the relevant parts of it that apply to the OP's question this could be a superb answer.